# How to remove all item in state using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

im made a Todo App using redux toolkit, and im trying to make a button which to clear all item in array;

Im try to set array to empty by using splice like this but doesn't work

```
clearList: (state) => {
      return state.splice(0, state.length);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `redux-toolkit` either update/mutate the `state` object ***or*** return the next state value, but not both.

```
clearList: (state) => {
  state.splice(0, state.length);
}
```

or since you are just wanting to clear the array you could just return a new empty array.

```
clearList: (state) => {
  return [];
}
```

You can read more on [Direct State Mutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation)

Comment: thanks! return [] it's actualy worked! I used return state: [] and  return state = [], both of them don't worked